# Loop through an array of objects and display in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, foreach, grid

I have an array as below:

```
var locations = [{
        plot: "24-17",
        address: "XYZ",
        city: "Something",
        pin: "24399",
        phone: "041678993"
    },    {
        plot: "24-18",
        address: "ABC",
        city: "Something",
        pin: "24398",
        phone: "041678995"
    },    {
        plot: "24-19",
        address: "DEF",
        city: "Something",
        pin: "24397",
        phone: "041678994"
    }];
```

Now, i want to loop through the array and display them int the below dom:

```
<div id="locations-grid">
  <div id="di-locations">
     <div id="plot"></div>
     <div id="address"></div>
     <div id="city"></div>
     <div id="pin"></div>
     <div id="phone"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Each object in the array corresponds to one location. I want to display all the locations as different columns in a css grid.

I tried

```
locations.map((item)=>{ 
    plot.innerHTML = item.plot;
    address.innerHTML = item.address; 
    city.innerHTML = item.city; 
    pin.innerHTML = item.pin; 
    phone.innerHTML = item.phone; 
});
```

But this displays only the last object in the array. This doesn't get me the 3 objects into 3 different columns of the grid.

Comment: could you show us what you've tried please ?

Comment: You want to get a dynamical table with these properties from your array where every object from the data-array will be represented in one table-row?

Comment: have a look at these https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_iteration.asp. its easy its like you did not search google first before asking

Comment: @jonatjano - I tried this: 'locations.map((item)=>{
    plot.innerHTML = item.plot;
    address.innerHTML = item.address;
    city.innerHTML = item.city;
    pin.innerHTML = item.pin;
    phone.innerHTML = item.phone;   
}); '  But this displays only the last object in the array. This doesn't get me the 3 objects into 3 different columns of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Putting your structure in DIVS is not the right way use a **TABLE** instead of it (here with a header-row). You had to dynamical build the rows and cell of it because you don't know how many rows will be needed and it's much more structured.
First get the handler from your table with **document.getElementById** Than create for every row a new table-row **TR** and then iterate through your data. For each property of it create a new cell **TD** and add to it's **innerHTML** the value. Append the TD to your row TR with **appendChild** because the elemnts is till now not in the DOM. After you have done this for every property append the TR to the table. Now the tablerow will be presented in the table.

```js
var locations = [{
        plot: "24-17",
        address: "XYZ",
        city: "Something",
        pin: "24399",
        phone: "041678993"
    },    {
        plot: "24-18",
        address: "ABC",
        city: "Something",
        pin: "24398",
        phone: "041678995"
    },    {
        plot: "24-19",
        address: "DEF",
        city: "Something",
        pin: "24397",
        phone: "041678994"
          }
];

let table = document.getElementById('di-locations');
locations.forEach(location => {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    Object.entries(location).forEach(value => { 
       let td = document.createElement('td');
       td.innerHTML= value;
       tr.appendChild(td);
    });
    table.appendChild(tr);
});
```

```css
td, th { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<div id="locations-grid">
  <table id="di-locations">
    <tr>
      <th>plot</th>
      <th>address</th>
      <th>city</th>
      <th>pin</th>
      <th>phone</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: [CSS grid layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) is a new thing to mimic tables. You _do_ use `div`s with it (as I show in my answer).

Comment: @bkis Thanks I didn't know this technique but in some cases it's helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You can [iterate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) over these location objects and append new [grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) items containing the location property data [as you go](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). From your question it's a little unclear how exactly the result should look like, but this snippet gives you something to build upon...

```js
var locations = [{
  plot: "24-17",
  address: "XYZ",
  city: "Something",
  pin: "24399",
  phone: "041678993"
}, {
  plot: "24-18",
  address: "ABC",
  city: "Something",
  pin: "24398",
  phone: "041678995"
}, {
  plot: "24-19",
  address: "DEF",
  city: "Something",
  pin: "24397",
  phone: "041678994"
}];

var container = document.getElementById("di-locations");

// iterate locations
for (loc of locations) {
  // iterate location properties
  for (var prop in loc) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(loc, prop)) {
      //create and append grid item
      var item = document.createElement("DIV");
      item.classList.add(loc[prop]);
      item.innerHTML = loc[prop];
      container.appendChild(item);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#di-locations {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#di-locations>* {
  padding: .8rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="locations-grid">
  <div id="di-locations"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This should help, shouldn't be too hard to turn into a grid:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="i"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var locations = [{
        plot: "24-17",
        address: "XYZ",
        city: "Something",
        pin: "24399",
        phone: "041678993"
    },    {
        plot: "24-18",
        address: "ABC",
        city: "Something",
        pin: "24398",
        phone: "041678995"
    },    {
        plot: "24-19",
        address: "DEF",
        city: "Something",
        pin: "24397",
        phone: "041678994"
    }];

txt = "<p>"; // Define txt so it can be accessed inside of functions
locations.forEach(foo); // Run foo for each item in the array

function foo(value,index,array) {
  txt = txt + "Plot: " + value["plot"] + "<br>"; // Add Plot: _____ to the end of txt
  txt = txt + "Address: " + value["address"] + "<br>"; // Similar to above
  txt = txt + "City: " + value["city"] + "<br><br>"; // Similar to above
}
document.getElementById("i").innerHTML = txt + "</p>"; // Set the inner html of i to txt
```

Comment: Creating HTML using string concatenation is... frowned upon.

Comment: And... did you just copy/paste the first code example from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_array_iteration.asp)?

Comment: No... this is how I would do it. Also @bkis thanks for the advice <3.